# Redis, how to increase all scores of a zset with ZINCRBY?

Tags: redis

Is there a way to increment all scores of a zset with one command? This is what I would like to do:

```
ZADD myzset 1 "first"
ZADD myzset 2 "second"
ZINCRBY myzset 2 "*"
ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "first"
2) "3"
3) "second"
4) "4"
```

but, `ZINCRBY myzset 2 "*"` does not work like that.

Answer (score 10):

There is no command for that, ZINCRBY can only increment for 1 member at a time. So if you want to accomplish this in an atomic and fast way you need to do a Lua script. Which should look something like this (first you get all members of the sorted set and then iterate through them and increment the score):

```
local zsetMembers = redis.call('zrange', KEYS[1], '0', '-1') 
for k,member in pairs(zsetMembers) do 
  redis.call('zincrby', KEYS[1], 1, member) 
end
```

And you can push this script to Redis with the [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) command.

Answer (score 0):

If you need do this task often Or this is a piece code of your app server, maybe you could use the pipeline to speedup the task. if your zset size if N, then there will be N RTTs between your client and redis server. If you use the pipeline ,just nedd one RTT which will save network transport time. more about this, refer this [document](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining). And the algorithm is same as @Liviu Costea.